# TYPO3 news extension multi language

Tags: typo3, typoscript, multilingual, tx-news

i am using the News system (news) extension. In the listing view I need to translate the "read more" text to my local language (german). 
I already found the translation file inside the plugins folder.

```
Path: /typo3conf/ext/news/Resources/Private/Language
```

Now I need to know if I just can overwrite this file or if I need to add my own translation file so the plugin is still perfectly updatable (and if so how does it work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is using the lfeditor extension https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/lfeditor/

read carefully the instructions about the editing modes!

Another possibility could be using TypoScript to override the labels - see
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Plugin/Index.html#local-lang-lang-key-label-key

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So i have this in the plugin language file:
   <trans-unit id="more-link" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Read more</source>
   </trans-unit>
so the key is "more-link" right? And my typoscript should be:
plugin.tx_news._LOCAL_LANG.de.more-link = Mehr erfahren
?

Comment: Because that doesn't work for me. Probably a problem with my installation. Thanks for all. I mark it as right because that prolly should work.

Comment: The syntax is correct; I tested it and it works. We need futher information about your configuration to diagnose why it does not work. Is "de" the main language or an alternative language?

Comment: It works now! en was the main language of the TYPO. I swapped it to de now it works fine. en is now the alternative lang.
Thank you!